# Associations between models in different application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, devise, single-sign-on

I have a client application that uses Devise for authentication. We have implemented SSO on another server. We want the client app to authenticate off of the SSO server using devise. Because at the moment there are 2 user models, I am wondering if it is possible to migrate/merge the client user model into the authentication user model, and carry over the associations. Is this possible and how so if they are separate applications?
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I well understood, what you are looking for : if you jhave already a `user` model, that you want to plug devise on, you can use this

```
rails g devise user
rake db:migrate
```

Ensure that you have already migrated the `user`, before running those devise command. And then you can do everything you want as commpleting your `user` model (`rails g migration add_whatever_to_users username`).

I strongly suggest you those very interesting [railscasts](http://railscasts.com/episodes?utf8=%E2%9C%93&search=devise)

Comment: Thanks but generating the user model is not the problem, its that we are currently ending up with 2 different user models working on the same table. Its a question of whether I can bring over dependencies from the client engine user model to the auth engine user model.

Comment: sorry I didn't understand what you mean. You can migrate your `user` model to a devise one, and dump it to be as the second one you builded